# Moving camera around an object in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

Previous posts here did not seem to address my problem.

I'm trying to get my camera to move around a specific point called "target". Target is an empty gameobject set at the center of my game. The idea is that the camera would not move any closer to or farther from target and would simply rotate around the target as though it were moving around an invisible sphere. The camera should always point at target. `transform.LookAt(target)` does just fine keeping the camera trained on the target, but I cant get the movement correct. Whether I'm moving along the horizontal or vertical axes, it always spirals directly into the target rather than just moving around it. Any ideas?

```
public class CameraController : MonoBehaviour {

public float speed;
public Transform target;

void Update () {
    transform.LookAt(target);

    if(Input.GetAxis("Vertical") != 0)
    {
        transform.Translate(transform.up * Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * Time.deltaTime * speed); //.up = positive y
    }

    if(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") != 0)
    {
        transform.Translate(transform.right * Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * Time.deltaTime * speed); //.right = positive x
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To rotate around a specific point I use `Transform.RotateAround`:

```
transform.RotateAround(target.position, transform.right, -Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * speed);
transform.RotateAround(target.position, transform.up, -Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * speed);
```

Or, if your target moves and you want to keep the same distance between the camera and your target, you can use [this piece of code](http://answers.unity3d.com/answers/768645/view.html) from my `answers.unity3d.com` page :

```
public class SphericalCam 
    : MonoBehaviour 
{
     public float MinDist, CurrentDist, MaxDist, TranslateSpeed, AngleH, AngleV;
     public Transform Target;

     public void Update()
     {
         AngleH += Input.GetAxis("Mouse X");
         AngleV -= Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y");
         CurrentDist += Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel");
     }

     public void LateUpdate()
     {
         Vector3 tmp;
         tmp.x = (Mathf.Cos(AngleH * (Mathf.PI / 180)) * Mathf.Sin(AngleV * (Mathf.PI / 180)) * CurrentDist + Target.position.x;
         tmp.z = (Mathf.Sin(AngleH * (Mathf.PI / 180)) * Mathf.Sin(AngleV * (Mathf.PI / 180)) * CurrentDist + Target.position.z;
         tmp.y = Mathf.Sin(AngleV * (Mathf.PI / 180)) * CurrentDist + Target.position.y;
         transform.position = Vector3.Slerp(transform.position, tmp, TranslateSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
         transform.LookAt(Target);
     }
 }
```

Comment: This still doesnt quite work. For one, it wont go all the way around in when rotating in the X axis (it stalls at the poles and oscillates). And when rotating around the y axis, no matter how far above or below the target you are, it will descend into orbit until its Y translation matches that of the target.

Comment: @DylanRussell I'm using these two functionalities in my projects and it seems to work fine. Are you sure it's caused by these?

Comment: Messing around with it, I actually notice the problem with the poles is that the local positive and negative axes "switch" when you reach a certain point rotating around the X axis. Any way to address this that you know of to get a smooth rotation around a target if you just hold the up or down key?

Comment: transform.RotateAround(target.position, transform.right, -Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * speed);
  transform.RotateAround(target.position, transform.up, -Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * speed); 

That is the code I am using. If you use that and just hold the up or down key (assuming you havent changed inputs), youll notice what happens when you get to the north and south poles of the object you are rotating around.

Comment: Ah, I fixed it! I did not remove transform.LookAt(target); and now it works perfectly! Thank you so much!

Comment: Okay I'll check how to fix this. For now I think you can use second script which should work okay.

Answer (score 3):

Camera rotation around target horizontally:

```
transform.RotateAround(target.position, target.forward, Time.deltaTime * speed);
```

Vertically:

```
transform.RotateAround(target.position, target.right, Time.deltaTime * speed);
```