# Instantiate gameobjects in a segment of a circle if you have radius of the circle

Tags: c#, algorithm, unity-game-engine

I want to instantiate gameobjects in a segment of a circle e.g in between 10 degrees and 100 degrees from a known vector3 position. (Imagine a shape of pizza). I found following code that helps me instantiate objects between 0 and 180 degrees. Can someone help me instantiate gameobjects between 10 and 100 degrees as an example.

```
Vector3 randomCircle ( Vector3 center ,   float radius )
{
    float ang = Random.value * 180;
    Vector3 pos;
    pos.x = center.x + radius * Mathf.Sin(ang * Mathf.Deg2Rad);
    pos.y = center.y + radius * Mathf.Cos(ang * Mathf.Deg2Rad);
    pos.z = center.z;
    return pos;
}
```

Comment: How about `float ang = Random.Range(10f, 100f)` ?

Comment: Seems to be working at my end! 
Still testing but looks great to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copying and modifying my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43187019/moving-camera-around-an-object-in-unity/43187454#43187454) to different topic would do what you need.

```
// get the new position 
public Vector3 OrbitPosition(Vector3 centerPoint, float radius, float angle)
{
    Vector3 tmp;
    // calculate position X
    tmp.x = Mathf.Sin(angle * (Mathf.PI / 180)) * radius + centerPoint.x;
    // calculate position Y
    tmp.y = Mathf.Sin(angle * (Mathf.PI / 180)) * radius + centerPoint.y;
    tmp.z = centerPoint.z;
    return tmp;
}

// instantiate element at random orbit position
public GameObject InstantiateRandom(GameObject toInstantiate, Vector3 centerPoint)
{
    // get calculated position
    Vector3 newPosition = OrbitPosition(centerPoint, 10.0f, Random.Range(10.0f, 100.0f));
    // instantiate a new instance of GameObject
    GameObject newInstance = Instantiate(toInstantiate) as GameObject; 
    // check if instance was created
    if ( newInstance )
    {
        // set position to the newly created orbit position
        newInstance.transform.position = newPosition;
    }
    // return instance of the newly created object on correct position
    return newInstance;
}
```